# Disable highlighting for tex files with texvim

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, plugin-vimtex

I want to use `vimtex` and enable highlighting for all filetypes, except `tex` files. For `tex` files I explicitly want to disable highlighting.

How could I do that?

Important: The solution should allow to use `<leader>ll` for compilation of the tex files, without enabling highlighting again!

Answer (score 1):

I would install a personal syntax file, e.g. in `.vim/syntax/tex.vim`, to override the default with the content:

```
let b:current_syntax = 'tex'
```

In addition, you should add

```
let g:vimtex_syntax_enabled = 0
```

to prevent vimtex from patching the syntax script.